# How to mock a GPS path in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, mocking, gps, location

There are some links about how to mock a location, but not so much about how to mock a full path in android. I want to test a Google Maps app by using predefined paths and checking how the app reacts to them. Is there a best practise way to test a whole path?

Comment: `test a Google Maps app`. Which one?

Comment: I use an app called Lockito, it mocks paths.